# Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1) for Api Key on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, certificate, sha1, api-key

I'm using an Ubuntu machine and trying to use Google Maps in an Android application.
If I use the console command to get the SHA-1 fingerprint:

```
/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

I get:
`04:30:10:2D:F9:D4:A5:3E:D0:C9:9B:1E:19:98:36:38:6C:0A:00:14`

My app does not work if I generate the apiKey using **this** fingerprint.

Now, if i create an app from scratch using gradle, in the google_maps_api.xml file I've found another SHA-1 fingerprint:

```
49:8E:C1:EB:2F:1B:72:A7:96:D7:ED:FA:59:3A:BF:EF:F4:55:5C:2B
```

The apiKey obtained using this fingerprint works fine, even for my first app.

Are they many SHA-1 fingerprints on the same machine? Where does the second one come from?

Comment: what did you use to create project before using gradle

Comment: the Ant build system. That was an old app which used google maps v1. It works if I use the SHA-1 and apiKey generated from the gradle project.

Comment: as both signatures are different its apparent both are different keys your are using. kindly check path of both

Comment: How can I get the path on the gradle project? The file google_maps_api.xml is built automatically, i don't know where should i look.

Comment: Could it be something like a release fingerprint and not a debug one? In this case, how can i extract it?